# Window.localstorage throws script error in MAC OS safari browser

Tags: javascript

I have tried `window.localStorage and window.sessionStorage`. both of them return below error

> **Security Error: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent**

It works properly in windows OS. .The issue in MAC only.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Quick search returns this [page](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4234) where [Nolan Lawson](https://github.com/nolanlawson) states:

> DOM Exception 18 usually means you exceeded the quota allowed on the device (50MB), although in some environments it's because Apple removed WebSQL support (e.g. WKWebView).

How much data are you attempting to store?

Comment: 3kb data only stored